# Linq to XML query works when returning single entity but needs to be of list<T>

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Given this XML:

```
<foo>
   <xxx>Some XXX</xxx>
   <bar Attr1="true">Some Bar</bar>     
   <bar Attr2="true">Some Bar #2</bar>
   <bar>Some Bar #3</bar>
   <bar>Some Bar #4</bar>
</foo>
```

I have this LINQ query:

```
var foos = from query in xmlData.Descendants("foo")
       from bars in query.Elements("bar")
       select new FooClass
       {
    xxx = (string)query.Element("xxx"),
    barCollection = new BarClass
    {
        display = bars.Value,
        attr1Exists = (answers.Attribute("Attr1") != null ? true : false)
        attr2Exists = (answers.Attribute("Attr2") != null ? true : false)
        }
       };
```

This works great if barCollection is defined as BarClass.

However I need it to be List<BarClass>.

I've tried other approaches, and got this to work if bar is a List<string>:

```
var foos = from query in xmlData.Descendants("foo") 
select new FooClass 
{ 
    xxx = (string)query.Element("xxx"), 
    bar = query.Elements("bar").Select(x => x.Value).ToList() 
};
```

But I can't find a way to mix the two.

Can someone show how to combine the two solutions so that BarCollection is populated as a user defined type, namely List<BarClass>?

**Update: Final working code below, using solutions provided**

```
var foos = from query in xmlData.Descendants("foo") 
select new FooClass 
{ 
    xxx = (string)query.Element("xxx"), 
    bar = query.Elements("bar").Select(x => new BarClass
    {
        display = x.Value,
        attr1Exists = x("Attr1") != null ? true : false),
        attr2Exists = x("Attr2") != null ? true : false)
        }

    ).ToList() 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.Select(x => x.Value)` to `.Select(x => new BarClass(...))`.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

So...rephrasing your question slightly....

you want a Foo class that has a Collection of BarClasses as one of its properties?

```
List<BarClass> mybars = Foo.Bars; // is this your aim?
```

If this is correct, then you don't need a select many (your second from clause)

you would do something almost exactly like your second approach....

```
  var foos = from query in xmlData.Descendants("foo")      
  select new FooClass
  {          
       xxx = (string)query.Element("xxx"), 
       Bars = query.Elements("bar").Select(x => new BarClass()
          {
             Attr1 = .. /// etc
             Attr2 = ....
          }).ToList();
  }
```

Comment: Wish I could give multiple correct answers.. This is exactly what was needed.